# JavaScript scoping - unexpected modification of class variable

Tags: javascript

I'm confused by the following scoping in JavaScript. I have a global object `Rummy` to which I then attach a `Manager` object.

The confusion is in `calculate`, where I store the player's current cards in a local variable `var cards`. I push a card into `cards`, but somehow this modifies the total cards in `this.current_player.cards`.

Why is this?

```
(function () {
    window.Rummy = window.Rummy || {};
})();

(function () {
    Rummy.Manager = Rummy.Manager || {};

    Rummy.Manager = (function () {
        var api = {},

        api.init = function () {
            this.players = createPlayers();
            this.current_player = this.players.mainPlayer;
            this.deck = [//some card objects in here];
            this.calculate(this.deck[this.deck.length-1]);
        };

        api.calculate = function (card) {
            // Create a new variable to store player's cards as to not modify the player's current cards...
            var cards = this.current_player.getCards(); 
            console.log('A: total cards', this.current_player.getCards());
            cards.push(card);
            console.log('B: total cards', this.current_player.getCards());
        };

        return api;
    })();
})();   

(function () {
    Rummy.Manager.init();
})();
```

`this.current_player.getCards();` initial total: 7

```
A's output: 8 cards
B's output: 8 cards
```

If I comment out `cards.push(AI_card);`:

```
A's output: 7 cards
B's output: 7 cards
```

If I'm declared `var cards` and only modifying the new array, why is it changing the player's cards array?

---

Player Class if needed:

```
var Player = function(manager, canvas, args) {
       this.cards = [];
       ...
};

Player.prototype = {

    constructor: Player,

    setCards : function (card) {
        this.cards.push(card);
    },

    getCards : function () {
        return this.cards;
    },
};
```

Comment: There is no "new array" like you're assuming. `getCards` returns the same array reference. If you want to return a shallow copy, you could do something like `return this.card.slice(0);`

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Is there a way to pass by value and not reference?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli where would I return `return this.card.slice(0)` from? From Player class instead of `return this.cards`?

Comment: If "by value" means create a shallow clone, then you need to do that manually.

Comment: They are passed by value, it just so happens that the value is the object reference.

Comment: @Growler JavaScript actually does pass-by-value, it's just the [value is a reference itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) .

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Is this a JavaScript thing? I'm coming from Java where I was used to using getters as such to simply return a shallow copy of the value when setting a new variable, which wouldn't modify the original value

Comment: I haven't done a great deal of Java but I'm pretty sure that's not the case. If you return a list from some method it doesn't automatically create a copy.